# Proof of AR(1) simulation

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive

I am trying to simulate an AR1 process which has a mean of $\mu $.

ie. $y_t- \mu = \Phi(y_{t-1}-\mu) + \epsilon_t$

[This link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821238/ar1-simulation-with-non-zero-mean) says that we should do :-

```
arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.8), n=53,sd=21) + 300
```

where $\mu = 300,\Phi= .8$, n = length of series

Can someone show me how this is working? How does adding $\mu$ to this equation:-

$y_t = \Phi (y_{t-1})+ \epsilon_t$

make it into :-

$y_t- \mu = \Phi(y_{t-1}-\mu) + \epsilon_t$

Comment: I figured it out. Put $x_t = y_t + \mu $ Then we plug it into both sides and solve for x_t.

Comment: In order to be more clear, we are given that $y_t = \Phi(y_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t $ We add to  each  y_t the mean, ie.  put $x_t = y_t +  \mu$ Substituting $y_t  = x_t - \mu$ we get $x_t -\mu = \Phi (x_{t-1} - \mu) + \epsilon_t $  So the newly generated variable satisfies the needed relation.

Comment: You *can* answer your own question instead of commenting under the post.